# Android Facebook Account Kit Crash - com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ConstrainedLinearLayout.onMeasure

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, account-kit

After upgrading Facebook Account Kit from version 4.28 to 4.31 I am seeing a new crash with the following stack trace:

```
atal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference
   at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6830)
   at android.widget.TextView.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TextView.java:8948)
   at android.view.View.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(View.java:13110)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17550)
   at android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:657)
   at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:610)
   at android.widget.Spinner.getBaseline(Spinner.java:456)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1120)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
   at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ConstrainedLinearLayout.onMeasure(ConstrainedLinearLayout.java:114)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
   at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ConstrainedLinearLayout.onMeasure(ConstrainedLinearLayout.java:97)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1260)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:337)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2027)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1185)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1391)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:773)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:759)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5284)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Reviewing the Upgrade Guide, I don't see any required steps related to our use-case:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4x

I'm tempted to revert back to version 4.28 but am concerned about additional risk that may cause to users already exposed to the newer version.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook apparently has a fix for this ready (but not yet released): https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/146171089525966/